# Partition by without Re-ordering the data

Tags: sql, sql-server

My current data is as follows:

[image: Current Data]

And I want  Data to be

[image: I want this Data]

When I use the row_number function it is reordering itself and giving me the wrong row_number,as below

[image: Wrong Result]

If we See "Adjusted conversion COst" value 0.160 is coming top of result and is numbered 1 which is wrong as per the first screenshot it should be numbered 3

Thanks

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  You can only do what you want if you have an ordering specified for the rows.  Please include the ordering information in the question.

Comment: My Query Is as follows:
   SELECT Colo1,
   row_number()over(Colol order by (select null))) //used "select null" in order by  since I dont want it to be ordered ,only partitoned 
        ,f7 
  FROM ['Total$']

Answer (score 0):

MYSQL Using Variable

Result - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/406f64/8/0

```
select 
colo1,f7,
if(colo1='Total Adj. Conversion Spend',@initVal:=@initVal+1,1) as RowNumber
from temp,(select @initVal:=0) vars
```

MS-SQL Using Rank and Row Number

I've used Row_Number() to preserve the order and then using Rank() inside a case statement

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/fde9f/15/0

```
select subquery_1.colo1,subquery_1.f7
,case when subquery_1.colo1='Total Adj. Conversion Spend' then 
rank() over (partition by colo1 order by rownum) else 1 end as rnk
from
(select *,row_number() OVER (ORDER BY (Select 0)) as rownum from temp) as subquery_1
order by subquery_1.rownum
```